# Javafx load a 3d model from blender in only code

Tags: javafx, model

I have been looking for a few days about how to use a model from blender in my javafx program I'm making in eclipse (i have the plugin to use javafx in it) but only found other programs that i don't want to use. Is there a way to load a model like you can a png file to display it on a canvas in only code with no programs but eclipse?

I used my phone to send this sorry if there are some english problems here.

Comment: Normaly that is what you searching for: http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html

Comment: My problem is i will need this for commercial use and i could not find any for that.

Comment: Never mind you found what i needed thank you for all the help i didn't see the commercial use part there.